# What is the importance of Ayatul-Kursi?

Tags: surat-al-baqarah, ayah

[Ayatul-Kursi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Baqara_255) ([Qur'an 2:255](https://quran.com/2/255)) is generally said to be of great benefits e.g. it's recitation is encouraged in order to come under divine protection among many other.

Sure it speaks of His Throne. But what makes it so important?

Is there a tradition from Muhammad (saww) which speaks of its importance (at such an exalted level)?

Also, traditions speaking of it's protective nature would be appreciated.

Comment: As phrased, this question just seems likely to attract a list of items (as it already has) rather than actual *answers*.  I reckon it needs more focus.

Answer (score 4):

There are ahadeeth mentioning it's greatness, but I do not know any Ahadeeth which explicitly mentions what makes it great or important.  But it is great because it encompasses all seven Usool of Allah names and attributes.  It is important because it is one of the reasons of entering Jannah:

> من قرأ آية الكرسي دبر كل صلاة لم يمنعه من دخول الجنة إلا الموت
>
> Whoever reads Ayatul Kursi after each obligatory salat, nothing will
> stop him from entering Jannah except death

[سنن الكبرى للنسائي(Annasa'i)](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=315&hid=9532&pid=)

It is also a protection against shaytaan, [Source](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/66/32).

For more information [see this(Arabic)](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/135452).